# Image not loading before Javascript+Python function ends

Tags: javascript, python, eel

I'm using python with eel to communicate with a local website as frontend. My code should display an image on a web page while in the middle of a long python function. The image only appears after the python function is executed, even though `<img>` is present in the HTML at the correct time.

Here's my Javascript code:

```
eel.expose(set_image);

function set_image() {
    document.getElementById("zoom-animate").innerHTML = '<img src="temp.png">';
}



function generate() {
    let source = document.getElementById("source").value;
    let keyword = document.getElementById("keyword").value;
    eel.generate(source, keyword);
}
```

And my Python code:

```
@eel.expose
def generate(source, keyword):
    # code that takes a long time to execute 1
    eel.set_image()
    # code that takes a long time to execute 2
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `generate()` function should call `set_image()` and immediately `return`.
That way the
[WSGI](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Web_Server_Gateway_Interface)
server can immediately send a `200` document to the web client.
As it stands, the web server is patiently waiting for your function to return.

Use a [celery](https://pypi.org/project/celery)
worker to complete the "long time to execute 2" task
in the background.